# Python Async integration (Internal Linking tool optimization )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how can I process multiple lines simultaneously from .csv or .xlsx files. Currently my app is trying to fetch data from each URL one by one and I know I can go around this by utilizing async/await (asyncio library). Couldn't find any clear statements from Google Custom Search API documentation that multiple requests at the time is restricted. Perhaps you can advise how can I optimize the app with async or any other alternatives to process data faster?

Internal linking tool is sending 1 request at once, if the uploaded file is extensive it can take hours to process all of the data. I need a way to simultaneously work on at least 50 requests.

Here is repo for more info:
`https://github.com/MSuika/LinkLoom.git`

Live version:
https://linkloom.streamlit.app/

Main function of the app:

```
def process_uploaded_file(uploaded_file):
    link = None
    uploaded_file.seek(0)
    if uploaded_file:
        file_extension = uploaded_file.name.split('.')[-1]
        if file_extension == "csv":
            df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
        elif file_extension == "xlsx":
            df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)

    first_row = df.iloc[0]
    domain = urlparse(first_row['target_page']).netloc

    results_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        keywords = [k.strip() for k in row['keyword'].split(',')]
        url_to_keyword = {}

        for keyword in keywords:
            try:
                query = f"site:{domain} {keyword} -inurl:{row['target_page']}"
                results = search(query, st.session_state['api_key'], st.session_state['cse_id'])
                link_list = [result['link'] for result in results.get('items', []) if 'link' in result]

                if not link_list:
                    print(f"No linking opportunities found for keyword: {keyword}")
                    st.info(f"No linking opportunities found for keyword: {keyword}") 
                    continue

                for link in link_list:
                    if link and link not in url_to_keyword:
                        if has_link_to_target(link, row['target_page']):
                            continue
                        text = get_page_text(link)
                        context, context_url = find_keyword_in_text(link, text, keyword)
                        if any(word in context for word in FORBIDDEN_WORDS) or context_url == '':
                            continue
                        url_to_keyword[link] = keyword
                        new_row = pd.DataFrame({
                            'keyword': [keyword],
                            'URL': [link],
                            'context': [context],
                            'context_url': [context_url],
                            'target_page': [row['target_page']]
                        })
                        results_df = pd.concat([results_df, new_row], ignore_index=True)
                        print(f"Successful request for keyword: {keyword}, URL: {link}")
            except Exception as e:
                st.error("An unexpected error occurred: " + str(e))
    return results_df
```